# RegEx: Remove all between (including) last underscore and file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the ISO codes and leading underscore from all elements in an array while keeping the file extension. The ISO code always comes before the file extension.

The source array:

```
var SrcFiles = [
"File_with_nr1_EN.txt",
"File_has_NR_3_ZHHK.txt",
"File_yy_nr_2_DE.pdf"
];
```

I want it to look like this:

```
var SrcFiles = [
"File_with_nr1.txt",
"File_has_NR_3.txt",
"File_yy_nr_2.pdf"
];
```

How do I go about this? Probably with a regex, but how? I found a good regex to only match the file endings, but don't really know how this might help me.

```
const re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
```

Comment: is it necessary to use regex ?? you can achieve it with simple string manipulation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture all up to the last `_`, match `_` and 1+ uppercase letters, and then capture a dot and the subsequent 1+ chars other than a dot up to the end of string:

```
/^(.*)_[A-Z]+(\.[^.]+)$/
```

and replace with `$1$2` where `$1` is the backreference to Group 1 and `$2` refers to the value in Group 2.

The `[A-Z]+` can be enhanced to `[A-Z]{2,}` (since ISO codes usually consist of at least 2 chars) and if a hyphen can appear there, use `_[A-Z-]{2,}`.

See the JS demo:

```js
var SrcFiles = [
"File_with_nr1_EN.txt",
"File_has_NR_3_ZHHK.txt",
"File_yy_nr_2_DE.pdf"
];

var res = SrcFiles.map(x => x.replace(/^(.*)_[A-Z]+(\.[^.]+)$/, '$1$2'));
// ES5
//var res = SrcFiles.map(function(x) {return x.replace(/^(.*)_[A-Z]+(\.[^.]+)$/, '$1$2'); });
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Look for a `_` followed by anything that isn't a `_` (`[^_]`), followed by: **a `.` followed by anything that is't a `_` at the end (`$`)**. The part in **bold** should be captured as `$1`.

```js
var SrcFiles = [
  "File_with_nr1_EN.txt",
  "File_has_NR_3_ZHHK.txt",
  "File_yy_nr_2_DE.pdf"
];

var re = /_[^_]+(\.[^_]+)$/;

console.log(SrcFiles.map(f => f.replace(re, "$1")));
```

[**REGEX101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/KM23X0/1)!

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
("^_)*_[A-Z]+(\.[^.]+",?)
```

Substitution:

```
$1$2
```

Checkout https://regex101.com/r/h0gukN/2

I joined the part before the ISO string, and the remainder together.
hope it helps :P

Answer (score 1):

Te pattern isn't so difficult. Take a look:

```
1_EN.txt
```

Stands for the following pattern: `\d+_\S+.`, where the `_\S+` you want to remove. Then, you can achieve this with the following replacement pattern:

```
s/(\d+)_\S+\./$1./g
```

The first group, followed with the "dot" is what you want to keep in the text. The 'g' constraint means that you want to keep replacing for all others matched patterns along the text.

Result details:

1. 1_EN.    replaced with  1.

   1.1. Group: 1
2. 3_ZHHK.  replaced with  3.

   2.1. Group: 3
3. 2_DE.    replaced with  2.

   3.1. Group: 2